# change UIButton title programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I want to toggle the text of a button based on clicks - every time the button is clicked the title will change from textA to TextB and so on. but when I use `button.titlelabel.text = @"blabla"`
but the text stays the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is worth a try:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClickEvent 
{
   [button setTitle:@"your title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: Might want to fix the spelling mistake in there. It should be `setTitle:` not `setTile:`

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
```